# how faker $generator property allow us to call formatters of other providers

Tags: php, faker

I am new to faker and also quite new to PHP. My question is rather towards how PHP works. For my question, I take Faker (a PHP library that generates fake data) as an example. For reference the url is:

```
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#faker-internals-understanding-providers
```

I was reading through the faker internals documentation and saw this code:

```
 <?php

namespace Faker\Provider;

class Book extends \Faker\Provider\Base
{
  public function title($nbWords = 5)
  {
    $sentence = $this->generator->sentence($nbWords);
    return substr($sentence, 0, strlen($sentence) - 1);
  }

  public function ISBN()
  {
    return $this->generator->ean13();
  }
}
```

What I am curious at is the ISBN method. It basically uses the $generated protected property of its base class to call a method named ean13(). But the arrow sign is usually used to call a method or get a variable within an object. I understand that $generator is an object of the class Generator as it was defined in the constructor like so:

```
    class Base
{
    /**
     * @var \Faker\Generator
     */
    protected $generator;

    /**
     * @var \Faker\UniqueGenerator
     */
    protected $unique;

    /**
     * @param \Faker\Generator $generator
     */
    public function __construct(Generator $generator)
    {
        $this->generator = $generator;
    }
```

But then I don't know where the program goes to find method ean13(). I opened the Generator class and find no method of that name. I was hoping for developers experienced in PHP to explain how it actually works to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled upon usage of what PHP calls "method overloading". (Note that "method overloading" has different meaning in other languages).
[PHP Doc for method overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

If you check the source code for the `Generator` class, you'll find a method in it called `__call()`.
What this does is catch all method calls to non-existing methods in the `Generator` class.
That method in turn calls the `format` method which does a lookup against the available formatters, in this case `ean13`, found in the `Barcode` class.

This is how you can write and load your own formatters, and do things like

`$faker->my_own_format()`

without having to touch the Generator class itself.